# [sender.date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]] gives different result?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

in Simulator :

```
"Sunday, July 20, 2014 at 7:00:42 PM Singapore Standard Time"
```

in Actual device:

```
"Sunday, 20 July, 2014 7:16:44 pm Singapore Standard Time"
```

Why????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simulator uses your Mac's locale, which may be different to the one on your device. In particular, Mac OS X allows much greater customisation of your locale in the Language & Region system preference pane.

Even if they're both set to the same thing, it's not guaranteed the output will be the same.